# Spring MVC Interceptors stop working when mixing annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a web app in which we stop supporting IE 7. To notify users of this change, we had a Spring MVC [HandlerInterceptorAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html) in charge of redirect the user to a warning url.

This is the relevant deployment descriptor (web.xml) content:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/web-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

This application only used old school Spring MVC controllers i.e. no annotations; recently I had to configure a controller using annotations using the following XML:

```
<beans>
    <!-- ... -->
    <!-- A lot of beans and controllers using Classic Spring MVC -->

    <bean id="browserVersionInterceptor" class="...BrowserVersionInterceptor" />

    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="detectHandlersInAncestorContexts" value="true" />
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="browserVersionInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <beans>
        <context:annotation-config />      
        <bean id="mvcAnnotationConfig"
        class="....MvcAnnotationConfig">
        </bean>
    </beans>
</beans>
```

And in that configuration I set the component scan for the controllers:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("package.to.controllers")
public class MvcAnnotationConfig {
    //...not much here
}
```

After applying this change, I found that no interceptors declared in the previous section of the file worked.

And the newly created controller with annotations:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Tickets.html")
public class SupportProcessController {

    @RequestMapping(method = GET)
    public ModelAndView show() {...}

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = POST, produces = "application/json")
    public Object apply() {...}
}
```

Any ideas why this happened?

Comment: What class are you using to load that context configuration?

Comment: The XML is loaded by Spring's DispatcherServlet

Comment: I think the default `ApplicationContext` class is an `XmlWebApplicationContext` and I don't think it handles processing `@Configuration` beans.

Comment: The javadoc says I can [by bootstrapping it](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html).

Comment: Good, so that's out of the question. Let's your web.xml and any other relevant contexts.

Comment: What annotations do you use in your controller ? And how are your interceptors declared ?

Comment: I just updated this. @SergeBallesta

Comment: The `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` does nothing for annotated controllers and you only defined the interceptor on the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`. The configured handler mappings by `@EnableWebMvc` don't do anything with that interceptor unless you configure it correctly. Also why didn't you simply use a `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and `<context:component-scan />`? No need for java config...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your controllers are declared using a `@ComponentScan` annotation, you could try to use a `<mvc:interceptors>` block in your xml config. Something like :

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <ref bean="browserVersionInterceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

But read the doc too ...

Comment: Interestingly that works... but the question remains of why they were disabled once I put the new <beans> block in the XML.